# Why does mean-centering in a univariate logistic regression change p-values?

Tags: logistic, statistical-significance, p-value, statsmodels, centering

I have a very simple logistic model with a single continuous independent variable and a two-category dependent variable. When I mean-center the IV, the p-value of the coefficient changes significantly, and I'm not sure why.

Example code snippet that reproduces the effect:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
x = [5, 5, 6, 6, 5, 6]
y = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
xc = x - np.mean(x)
lr1 = sm.MNLogit(y, x)
model = lr1.fit()
lr2 = sm.MNLogit(y, xc)
model2 = lr2.fit()
print(model.pvalues)
print(model2.pvalues)
```

```
0.423
1.
```

Shouldn't the significance level of the coefficient not depend on the predictor variable's scale? All I can find from other threads is that centering will change the significance of interaction effects, but that's not applicable here.

I'm also wondering which of the two results I should ultimately use to determine if there is a significant relationship between the two variables. Intuitively, the model with centered input seems "more" correct, given that in this data set there is no relationship at all.

Comment: When  I run this in R, the p-value of 0.423 is associated with the intercept, and the p-value of 1 is associated with $x$, with both versions of $x$.  Are you sure your output is what you think it is?

Comment: I'm betting this has to do with the lack of intercept.

Comment: I suspect this may not be a good illustrative example , as $x$ and $y$ appear to be independent.  Nor do I understand how both can exceed $1$ in a logistic regression

Comment: I wonder how many disastrous decisions have been made throughout the world on account of statsmodels not automatically including an intercept? It's certainly wasted some of my time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `statsmodels` package does not include an intercept. When you include an intercept, only the intercept p-value changes (which makes sense for centering the feature).

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
x = [5, 5, 6, 6, 5, 6]
y = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
xc = x - np.mean(x)
lr3 = sm.MNLogit(y, sm.tools.add_constant(x))
model3 = lr3.fit()
lr4 = sm.MNLogit(y, sm.tools.add_constant(xc))
model4 = lr4.fit()
print(model3.pvalues)
print(model4.pvalues)
```

This happens in an OLS linear regression, too, and the visualization is easier.

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
xc <- x - mean(x)
y <- c(1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 155)
L1 <- lm(y ~ 0 + x)
L2 <- lm(y ~ x)
L3 <- lm(y ~ 0 + xc)
L4 <- lm(y ~ xc)

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(x, y)
abline(a = 0, b = summary(L1)$coef[1], col = 'red')
abline(a = summary(L2)$coef[1], b = summary(L2)$coef[2])
plot(xc, y)
abline(a = 0, b = summary(L3)$coef[1], col = 'red')
abline(a = summary(L4)$coef[1], b = summary(L4)$coef[2])
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
```

[image]

Black represents the regression models with intercepts; red represents the models without intercepts.

When there is an intercept in the model, all the centering does is shift the data to the left or right, but the slope does not change (notice how the black lines are parallel). However, when there is no intercept, the line has to fit the data as best it can while also having a particular y-intercept (zero), resulting in the line twisting and changing the slope (notice how the red lines are not parallel).

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @lua It's a design decision to omit the intercept. While my naïve thinking disagrees with it, we do have a `statsmodels` developer on here who might be able to share why the intercept is excluded. Having interacted with him a few times, I expect there to be a compelling reason.

Comment: statsmodels does NOT make any changes to the design matrix provided by the user, unless formulas are used. Now we are stuck with it, the discussion and decision was 14 years ago. https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/8223 (I never had a strong preferences for adding or not adding constant.) Main advantage of not touching the provided design matrix is that we do not need to make a copy of it in most cases and so save time and memory. Use formulas if you want convenience over speed!

Comment: WOW that's quite the caveat to a Python package.

Comment: If you use formulas in statsmodels, then it's about the same as in R or other packages. If you use pandas or numpy interface, then statsmodels assumes that you know what you want and provide that.